# Defining greyshade colormaps depending on number of elements

Tags: python, colors, seaborn, color-palette

I have defined the following dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(DataMatrix_DCM,columns=['shape','dn','nis','Ds','Ibs','kVsfL','kHL','T_fund','Fa_max'])
```

and have `plotvars=['nis','Ds','Ibs','kVsfL','kHL']`

I am using the Seaborn relplot to generate plots. The code is as follows:

```
for vidx,vname in enumerate (plotvars):
g=sns.relplot(x="dn",y="Fa_max",col='shape',hue=vname,col_wrap=2,kind="scatter",palette=**###**,data=df,legend="full",edgecolor=None).set_titles("section shape: {col_name}")
```

Each of the parameters appearing alternately as "hue" has a different number of values. I would like to define figure-specific color palettes, all ranging between the colors (`cplim1,cplim1,cplim1`) and  (`cplim2,cplim2,cplim2`), but with a different number of elements in the palette vector (e.g., a different number of shades of gray, but all ranging between (0,0,0) and (0.5,0.5,0.5)).

I am looking for a way to automatize the definition of these palettes based on the number of unique values in the "hue" variable. Perhaps using linspace?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function which successfully generates a jagged array defining a grayscale color palette:

```
def greycolorpalette(df,vname):
    colidx=np.argwhere(df.columns.isin([vname])).ravel()
    colpal=np.linspace(0.8,0,num=len(np.unique(df.iloc[:,colidx])))
    colvec=[]
    for cidx,cval in enumerate (colpal):
        colvec.append(np.repeat(cval,3))
    return colvec
```